# How does `groupby` combine with `cummin`?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to understand the result of the below and specifically the results due to the line that contains the chained `groupby.cummin()` methods.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'Pos': [np.nan, np.nan,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,1.,  1.,  1.,  1.], 
'Stop': [np.nan, np.nan, 122.86, 122.86, 128.  , 128.  , 128.  , 128.  , 128.  , 125.8 , 125.8 , 124.05, 123.95, 123.85, 123.85, 123.85, 123.85], 
'tmp': [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True]}, 
index = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=17))

df
            Pos    Stop    tmp
2022-01-01  NaN     NaN  False
2022-01-02  NaN     NaN  False
2022-01-03  1.0  122.86   True
2022-01-04  1.0  122.86   True
2022-01-05 -1.0  128.00   True
2022-01-06 -1.0  128.00   True
2022-01-07 -1.0  128.00  False
2022-01-08 -1.0  128.00   True
2022-01-09 -1.0  128.00   True
2022-01-10 -1.0  125.80   True
2022-01-11 -1.0  125.80   True
2022-01-12  1.0  124.05   True
2022-01-13  1.0  123.95  False
2022-01-14  1.0  123.85   True
2022-01-15  1.0  123.85  False
2022-01-16  1.0  123.85   True
2022-01-17  1.0  123.85   True

df.groupby(['Pos','Stop'])['tmp'].cummin()
2022-01-01   -1
2022-01-02   -1
2022-01-03    1
2022-01-04    1
2022-01-05    1
2022-01-06    1
2022-01-07    0
2022-01-08    0
2022-01-09    0
2022-01-10    1
2022-01-11    1
2022-01-12    1
2022-01-13    0
2022-01-14    1
2022-01-15    0
2022-01-16    0
2022-01-17    0
```

Why does this produce -1 as a result for the first two rows? I thought `cummin` applied to `NaN`s produced `NaN`s not -1.  Also, unsure about the logic behind how the other values are generated.  Any help with understanding the logic behind how `groupby` and `cummin` work in this scenario would be appreciated.

Comment: `I thought cummin applied to NaNs produced NaN` - but you use column `tmp`, so no `NaN`s

Comment: If use `print (df.groupby(['Pos','Stop'])['Stop'].cummin())` then get `NaN`s

Comment: @jezrael Good point but still unclear as to why -1 is produced on the first two rows of the `tmp` column?

Comment: yes, reason is `NaN`s groups, looking why

Comment: cannot find it in pandas github issues. Because I think it is bug.